# What is the code to get the username from an MVC Controller of an MVC web app

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller

I am trying to get the username in an MVC Web app which is published to an IIS, but it does not work.
These are the 3 things I have tried:

1)
`public string userName = System.Environment.UserName;`

2)
`public string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;`

3)
In the view:
`@Html.Label((string)ViewBag.Name)`

In the controller:
`ViewBag.Name = userName;`

It works when I debug the app locally on my machine.  Although, when I go to the website it does not get my username, instead it looks like it gets something from the IIS?  I simply would like to get the username of the person on the website and no other functionalities.
I added a photo of IIS authentication, I do not know if it matters but I am making sure I am not missing anything.
Could you please help me with this?  Thank you very much in advance.
[image]

Comment: do you want the actual name of the user, which he uses in your application or are you looking for the user on which your website is run in iis?

`User.Identity.Name` in the controller returns normaly the username, which is used to authenticate the user

Comment: Controller's have a property called User which will contain what you want, assuming the user has logged in. The reason it's "working locally" is that the methods you're attempting are to get the user that the application is running as, not the currently logged in user accessing the site. If you're running locally, they'll often be one and the same.

Comment: My app does not have a login as of now.  I am trying to get the username of the person that goes to the website.  I tried the code I included in the question but it only works in debug, when I actually go to the website it does not.  I am a newbie and hope I am giving you all you need to help me.  Thank  you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.  I had to make (1)Anonymous Authentication to Disabled  and  (2)Windows Authentication to Enabled in both the project properties and in the IIS Authentication.

Now I am getting my last name back "Webster" but I would like to get NSantagata(first initial of my first name and last name) or Fieldaero\nicola.santagata.  How could I do that?
This is the code I have:

In the Controller:
`var userName = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
ViewBag.Name = userName;`
[/code]

In the View:
`@Html.Label((string)ViewBag.Name)`

If I do it directly from the view with code [code]@Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name[/code]
I get what I want, that is Fieldaero\nicola.santagata,  but I do not know how to get the same result in the controller.  I will then use the value in the controller to execute other code.  Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, to get user name, you can use this:

`var userName = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: I added in the controller  `ViewBag.Name = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;`  and in the view  `@Html.Label((string)ViewBag.Name) `  to see if the username would fill the label, but nothing.  It works in debug but not when I run the website.  I also saw on another forum that in the project properties I should set the Anonymous Authentication to Disabled  AND  the Windows Authentication to Enabled;  I am not sure if the latter would make any difference.

Comment: I get my username which fills the label in debug,  but when I run the web app that same label is empty